# Modify the hover panel on video thumbnails on Sharepoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, hover-panel

I would like to add the Date and Author of the video when someone hovers over the video thumbnail. I am using the Sharepoint Online version. Is this possible and how do I do so? Thank you!!!

[image]